# validation on textbox (no space)

Tags: asp.net

i have a webpage in that i have a text box, my requirement is i don't want to give space in the textbox if user give space in textbox it give indication no space in the textbox

Comment: Client side validation, server side validation, or both?

Comment: i want mainly client side if possible both mr.chris missal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you intended to capture a value where spaces aren't a valid character, you could use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox"
    ErrorMessage="Spaces are not allowed!" ValidationExpression="[^\s]+" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox" 
    ErrorMessage="Value can't be empty" />
```

This would prevent "hello world" and "data base" since they contain spaces, and would only allow "helloworld" and "database" as valid values. You must use a RequiredFieldValidator in conjunction with it to prevent blank entries since the RegularExpressionValidator does not prevent that on its own.

Specify the name of the textbox in the `ControlToValidate` property.

Comment: Thank u Mr. Ahmad Mageed i got it r u indian reply please

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**RegularExpressionValidator control**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Spaces are not permitted" 
  ControlToValidate="txt1"
  ValidationExpression="[^\s]+" />
```

The pattern `[^\s]+` means "one or more characters that is not a space". So if any of the characters is a space, it will fail.

Comment: i think u not understand for suppose user enter 'data base' in textbox i want rise the message that no space between the words that is user have to enter without empty space like 'database'

Comment: @Surya thanks, I understand better now. I've revised the answer to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you all
to remove your spaces in your document please try It.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txttitlename" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Spaces are not acceptable" ontrolToValidate="txttitlename" ValidationExpression="[^\s]+" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTML` page or `Asp.Net` page
only  **pattern="[^\s]+"**  in side `TextBox`

```
<input id="Text1" pattern="[^\s]+" type="text" />
```