# Error when using RequiredFieldValidator control for FreeTextBox control

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page:

```
...
<tr>
<asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" ForeColor="#CC3300"></asp:Label>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="Alert" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" HeaderText=""/>
<tr/>
<tr>
<FTB:FreeTextBox id="FTB" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="FTB" 
CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Content cannot be empty." ToolTip="Content cannot be empty." ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<tr/>
```

The first time, the code works fine when I let the FTB empty --> FailureText="`Content cannot be empty.`";

The 2nd time, I press `space` to input many `spaces` in FTB --> FailureText doesnt show and the program does the next codes.

I have used `RequiredFieldValidator` control before but it worked fine for both null or space value.

Help! I really dont know why the `RequiredFieldValidator` accept space value here???

Comment: When you've used the `RequiredFieldValidator` before, was it with this third-party `FreeTextBox` control or the built-in `TextBox` control? I wonder if that could be the problem (i.e. the validator isn't working the same for a third-party control).

Comment: @ledbutter but it works fine if I let the FreeTextBox empty in the first time.

Comment: @ledbutter I have used RequiredFieldValidator with Textbox control only

Comment: I don't think you understood me, here you are using the `RequiredFieldValidator` with a third-party control, FreeTextBox. You claimed to have used this validator before and its worked for space values, and I was curious whether those previous instances were with this same FreeTextBox control or if, instead, you were using the built-in TextBox control.

Comment: oh, I understood you already, I just didnt say it clearly. I have used RequiredFieldValidator before with Textbox control only, so it alway works fine. Now, I use it with FreeTextBox, as you said: the RequiredFieldValidator may be not work with the third-party, why it still show the FailureText in the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help. Its not exactly the same, but it sounds like you need to check if only spaces have been entered.

[validation on textbox (no space)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570402/validation-on-textbox-no-space)

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox"
    ErrorMessage="Spaces are not allowed!" ValidationExpression="[^\s]+" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox" 
    ErrorMessage="Value can't be empty" />
```

edit...

If you are ok with doing some work server side, this would be an easier solution...

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox1.Text))
{
      lblError.Text ="Enter required field";
}
```